# optimized VennDiagram with internal labels r

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to plot a venn diagram in an optimized way (see below) and with the cases as internal labels (not the number of cases in each intersection). I know there are post for each of them but non of the solutions allowed me to do both.

I have this:

```
x <- list()
x$A <- as.character(c("Per_36","Cent","CeM","vDG","LAVL","RSGd"))
x$B <- as.character(c("vCA1","DLE","Per_36","vDG","DIE","Per_35"))
x$C <- as.character(c("vCA1","Cg1","LAVL", "RSGc", "RSGd","Per_35","Per_36"))
x$D <- as.character(c("Por","Cg1","RSGc","LAVL","Per_35","RSGd","Per_36"))


require(VennDiagram)
v0 <-venn.diagram(x, lwd = 3, col = c("red", "green", "orange", "blue"),
                fill = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), apha = 0.5, filename = NULL)
grid.draw(v0)
overlaps <- calculate.overlap(x)
overlaps <- rev(overlaps)
for (i in 1:length(overlaps)){
  v0[[i+8]]$label <- paste(overlaps[[i]], collapse = "\n")
}

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(v0)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Regarding the organization of the venn diagramI want to do this:

```
c <- venn(x, simplify = TRUE, small = 0.5, intersections = TRUE)
```

[image]

which I got from package `gplots()` using the `venn` function with `simplify = TRUE`. However, in the venn function, I seem to no be able to replace the counts by the names of the labels. I used the intersections = TRUE, which by the description of the argument should work, but it doesn't (although if I look inside the variable c, the info is there).

```
    Logical flag indicating if the returned object should have the attribute 
"individuals.in.intersections" featuring for every set a list of individuals
 that are assigned to it.
```

Question: Using `VennDiagram`package, is there a way to do exactly the same as the `simplify` argument does in the `venn` function from `gplots` package?

Question 2: Using the `venn` function from `gplots` package, is there a way to display the names of each element instead of the element counts? Like I did in the 'venn.diagram' function?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am trying to draw a Venn diagram with internal labels and your question is a good example, I have only 3 lists so I cannot get it to work because I cannot figure out why you are addin 8 to the index in this line: `v0[[i+8]]$label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach which is by far no solution rather a hack.

```
# Print a venn and save it to an object
a <- venn(list(letters[1:5], letters[3:8]))
# save the intersections
b <- attr(a, "intersections")

# find the coordinates
s <- seq(0,500,100); abline(h=s); text(s, y=s, x=0)
s <- seq(0,500,50);  abline(v=s); text(s, y=0, x=s)
```

[image]

```
# the hack, destroy the venn to avoid the plotting of the internal numbers 
rownames(a) <- letters[1:nrow(a)]
a
plot.venn(a)
>Error in data[n, 1] : subscript out of bounds

# include the internal labels
text(200,300,paste(b$`01`,collapse = "\n"))
text(200,200,paste(b$`11`,collapse = "\n"))
text(200,100,paste(b$`10`,collapse = "\n"))
```

[image]

It's annoying with multiple venns. Otherwise you can save the venn as an `.svg` and edit it with inkscape or similar softwares or ask the developer by email.

Edit:
If your plots looking alwas the same you can check the source code for the venn function (In RStudio by hitting `F2`) and copy paste the positions for 4 and 5 circle venns and replace the labels function `lab("1000", data)` with your desired labels.

For 4 circles:

```
      text(35, 250, lab("1000", data))
      text(140, 315, lab("0100", data))
      text(260, 315, lab("0010", data))
      text(365, 250, lab("0001", data))
      text(90, 280, lab("1100", data), cex = small)
      text(95, 110, lab("1010", data))
      text(200, 50, lab("1001", data), cex = small)
      text(200, 290, lab("0110", data))
      text(300, 110, lab("0101", data))
      text(310, 280, lab("0011", data), cex = small)
      text(130, 230, lab("1110", data))
      text(245, 75, lab("1101", data), cex = small)
      text(155, 75, lab("1011", data), cex = small)
      text(270, 230, lab("0111", data))
      text(200, 150, lab("1111", data))
```

### Edit

Nowadays I would switch to a ggplot solution

```
ggVennDiagram::ggVennDiagram(x)
```

[image]

Comment: I need to generate many of these diagrams, your suggestion would require an attention to each diagram that I initially don't want to spend. I will only do it if I really need to. But thanks. It is a way to put it there.
Both functions allows you to get each element in each intersections, they just don't allow you to put them into the diagram in a more presentable way.